# Conversion of a decimal to double number in C# results in a difference

Tags: c#, double, decimal

Summary of the problem:

For some decimal values, when we convert the type from decimal to double, a small fraction is added to the result.

What makes it worse, is that there can be two "equal" decimal values that result in different double values when converted.

Code sample:

```
decimal dcm = 8224055000.0000000000m;  // dcm = 8224055000
double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(dcm);    // dbl = 8224055000.000001

decimal dcm2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dbl); // dcm2 = 8224055000
double dbl2 = Convert.ToDouble(dcm2);  // dbl2 = 8224055000.0

decimal deltaDcm = dcm2 - dcm;         // deltaDcm = 0
double deltaDbl = dbl2 - dbl;          // deltaDbl = -0.00000095367431640625
```

Look at the results in the comments. Results are copied from debugger's watch.
The numbers that produce this effect have far less decimal digits than the limit of the data types, so it can't be an overflow (I guess!).

What makes it much more interesting is that there can be two **equal** decimal values (in the code sample above, see "dcm" and "dcm2", with "deltaDcm" equal to zero) resulting in **different** double values when converted. (In the code, "dbl" and "dbl2", which have a non-zero "deltaDbl")

I guess it should be something related to difference in the bitwise representation of the numbers in the two data types, but can't figure out what! And I need to know what to do to make the conversion the way I need it to be. (like dcm2 -> dbl2)

Comment: I've reported this issue on MS Connect. Here's the link:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=498340

Comment: I am not sure what is the reason, but it seems the problem is in the (6) large decimal places. I tested with 5 decimal places and works fine. I have similar scenario where I transform from decimal to double and back, and since my precision is only 2 decimal places, my code is safe converted.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Interesting - although I generally don't trust normal ways of writing out floating point values when you're interested in the exact results.

Here's a slightly simpler demonstration, using [`DoubleConverter.cs`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which I've used a few times before.

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal dcm1 = 8224055000.0000000000m;
        decimal dcm2 = 8224055000m;
        double dbl1 = (double) dcm1;
        double dbl2 = (double) dcm2;

        Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(dbl1));
        Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(dbl2));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
8224055000.00000095367431640625
8224055000
```

Now the question is why the original value (8224055000.0000000000) which is an integer - and exactly representable as a `double` - ends up with extra data in. I strongly suspect it's due to quirks in the algorithm used to convert from `decimal` to `double`, but it's unfortunate.

It also violates section 6.2.1 of the C# spec:

> For a conversion from decimal to float or double, the decimal value is rounded to the 
>   nearest double or float value. While this conversion may lose precision, it never causes 
>   an exception to be thrown.

The "nearest double value" is clearly just 8224055000... so this is a bug IMO. It's not one I'd expect to get fixed any time soon though. (It gives the same results in .NET 4.0b1 by the way.)

To avoid the bug, you probably want to normalize the decimal value first, effectively "removing" the extra 0s after the decimal point. This is somewhat tricky as it involves 96-bit integer arithmetic - the .NET 4.0 `BigInteger` class may well make it easier, but that may not be an option for you.

Comment: This is a bug IMO too.
Have you/anyone reported this to Microsoft? I'm searching MS Connect and can't see anything related. So, I'm posting it.
Just want to know if they do confirm this as a bug or not.

Comment: 96-bit arithmetic is not necessary in this particular case, because one can get `decimal` to do the heavy lifting :)

Comment: Fascinating bug! As Anton Tykhyy notes, this is almost certainly because the representation of decimals with lots of extra precision is no longer "natively" in integers that fit into a double without representation error. I would be willing to bet up to a dollar that this bug has been in OLE Automation for fifteen years -- we use the OA libraries for decimal coding. I happen to have an archive of OA sources from ten years ago on my machine; if I have some free time tomorrow I'll take a look.

Comment: Customer support doesn't get much better than this :)

Comment: @Jon, I've used a part of your answer when reporting this issue on MS Connect (The C# spec part). Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Irchi - if you've already got Eric's ear, you've got a good head-start ;-p

Comment: With regard to the "why", try dividing 2E23/1E21, or 2E25 by 1E23, and see how the results compare with decimal-to-double conversions which would involve those divisions.

Comment: I recently got this issue when retrieving values from Oracle database. No integers involved : Oracle Number(3,1) retrieved in a DataRow containing objects, object containing intended value in QuickWatch. Using `Convert.ToDouble(object)` returns bad values : 8.4 becomes 8.39999..., 9.1 becomes 9.1000003... . My ugly workaround : round values returned by Convert using the expected precision of the oracle value.

Comment: @Keorl: Well what is the execution-time type of the object? I'd expect it to be `decimal`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : it's a `Single`

Comment: @Keorl: Okay - that's really unfortunate. If you're trying to preserve *decimal* digits to a specific precision, `decimal` is a much better type to use... it's a shame if the database is converting to `float` automatically :(

Comment: @EricLippert I'm coming a long way back, but do you have any more information on this bug? Was it corrected?

Comment: [FOR JAVA ]Hi, i used same, But the problem is both anser are different my decimal output was 13555261857.79 and when converted to double its 1.355526185779E10 .. How do i get same output after converting decimal to double. I'm talking about java

Comment: @user13926345: Given that you're asking about a different situation (given that Java doesn't have a type equivalent to C#'s `decimal` type) and on a different platform, and more than 10 years after this question was asked, it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: After more than 10 years, bug is still not fixed. There is no Connect portal and i can't find if this bug is even acknowledged/confirmed or rejected.

Answer (score 26):

The answer lies in the fact that `decimal` attempts to preserve the number of significant digits. Thus, `8224055000.0000000000m` has 20 significant digits and is stored as `82240550000000000000E-10`, while `8224055000m` has only 10 and is stored as `8224055000E+0`. `double`'s mantissa is (logically) 53 bits, i.e. at most 16 decimal digits. This is exactly the precision you get when you convert to `double`, and indeed the stray `1` in your example is in the 16th decimal place. The conversion isn't 1-to-1 because `double` uses base 2.

Here are the binary representations of your numbers:

```
dcm:
00000000000010100000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000100
01110101010100010010000001111110 11110010110000000110000000000000
dbl:
0.10000011111.1110101000110001000111101101100000000000000000000001
dcm2:
00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001 11101010001100010001111011011000
dbl2 (8224055000.0):
0.10000011111.1110101000110001000111101101100000000000000000000000
```

For double, I used dots to delimit sign, exponent and mantissa fields; for decimal, see [MSDN on decimal.GetBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx), but essentially the last 96 bits are the mantissa. Note how the mantissa bits of `dcm2` and the most significant bits of `dbl2` coincide exactly (don't forget about the implicit `1` bit in `double`'s mantissa), and in fact these bits represent 8224055000. The mantissa bits of `dbl` are the same as in `dcm2` and `dbl2` but for the nasty `1` in the least significant bit. The exponent of `dcm` is 10, and the mantissa is 82240550000000000000.

**Update II:** It is actually very easy to lop off trailing zeros.

```
// There are 28 trailing zeros in this constant —
// no decimal can have more than 28 trailing zeros
const decimal PreciseOne = 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000m ;

// decimal.ToString() faithfully prints trailing zeroes
Assert ((8224055000.000000000m).ToString () == "8224055000.000000000") ;

// Let System.Decimal.Divide() do all the work
Assert ((8224055000.000000000m / PreciseOne).ToString () == "8224055000") ;
Assert ((8224055000.000010000m / PreciseOne).ToString () == "8224055000.00001") ;
```

Comment: This makes sense, but see Jon Skeet's answer.
Logically, specifying more significant digits should result in a more accurate conversion, not a worse one!
Is there a way to convert the decimal to one which has "less" significant digits? This should result in a better conversion in my case!

Comment: The conversion *is* more accurate — you get 6 extra digits — but the result is not what you expect because decimal's and double's bases are different. I'll add example momentarily.

Comment: It's not a more accurate conversion. The exact value of the decimal is available, so should be returned. I can see why it happens, but that doesn't make it right :)

Comment: Well, if you understand "accurate" in this sense, I agree.

Comment: Thanks, binary representations are very helpful.
I know this is what happens, but my question is "why" exactly does the conversion place that "1" at the end? The conversion from a higher-precision value to a lower-precision value is supposed to perform rounding. It's like when converting "0.0" to integer, it results 0, but converting "0.000000000000" to integer results 1!

Comment: It is rounding, but not to a decimal digit (base 10), but to a binary digit (base 2).

Comment: @Blindy Rounding to Base 2 should produce the same result. Why when more digits are specified in the decimal it gets rounded to "1" but when fewer digits are specified it gets rounded to "0" ?

Comment: That's a clever bit of code, but I don't know whether the algorithm for deciding the resulting number of significant digits is well-specified. I think I'd personally rather use a big integer library and do it from a more theoretical point of view - but as I said, it's a nifty bit of code.

Comment: As for "accurate" - a fairly simple measure of accuracy is "what's the difference between the exact number being represented to start with, and the the exact value of the result of the conversion"? 0 represents complete accuracy - at least in terms of the magnitude of the number, and is available in this case. That's what I meant. As double doesn't have a concept of "the number of significant digits" I don't believe the accuracy can measured in those terms. (It could for other conversions, e.g. to another type which *did* preserve the number of significant digits.)

Comment: Good point about double not having significant digits. Also, there is a much easier way to trim off the trailing zeros than that piece of code I wrote (see code sample).

Comment: Good job on the PreciseOne trick. I plan to use this before all decimal to double conversions to ensure that the precision/representation of the decimal doesn't cause inconsistencies during the cast/conversion.

Answer (score 4):

The article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) would be an excellent place to start.

The short answer is that floating-point binary arithmetic is necessarily an *approximation*, and it's not always the approximation you would guess. This is because CPUs do arithmetic in base 2, while humans (usually) do arithmetic in base 10. There are a wide variety of unexpected effects that stem from this.

Comment: Thanks for the article link, it's a very long one but I will try to read it.
Base 2 arithmetic vs. Base 10 arithmetic is what I was suspicious of, but there are two points:
1. decimal has 28-29 significant digits, and double has 15-16 significant digits. 8 significant digits are enough for my number. Why should it treat like that? And as long as there is a representation of the original number in double, why the conversion should result in another one?
2. What about the two "same" decimal values getting converted to different doubles?

Comment: The number of significant digits isn't particularly relevant - "0.1" only has one significant digit, but still isn't representable in float/double. The point about there *being* an exact representation available is a much more significant one. As for the two values giving different doubles - they're *equal* but they're not the *same*.

Comment: Is there a way of converting those "equal but not same" decimals to each other? And is there a way to see that in the debugger? (I guess I should see the bitwise representation, but there's not such an option in VS. And "Hexadecimal display" doesn't work this way either)

Comment: Decimal.GetBits will give you the bitwise representation - you'd want to normalize by way of that. It won't be easy :( Do you know that the value is *actually* an integer? If so, that would help...

Comment: The number is "actually" an integer for this instance. But it can be a non-integer. What's for sure, is that it doesn't (and won't) have 16 significant digits.

Comment: Irchi: it's very easy to convert "equal but not same" decimals, see my code sample. Also `Decimal.ToString()` faithfully shows you trailing zeros, so you can distinguish "equal but not same" decimals by that even in VS debugger's normal watch etc. windows.

Answer (score 3):

To see this problem more plainly illustrated try this in LinqPad (or replace all the .Dump()'s and change to Console.WriteLine()s if you fancy).

It seems logically incorrect to me that the precision of the decimal could result in 3 different doubles. Kudos to @AntonTykhyy for the /PreciseOne idea:

```
((double)200M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 199.99999999999997
((double)200.0000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.00000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200.00000000000003
((double)200.000000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)200.0000000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 199.99999999999997
((double)200.00000000000000000000000000M).ToString("R").Dump(); // 199.99999999999997

"\nFixed\n".Dump();

const decimal PreciseOne = 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000M;
((double)(200M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.000000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.0000000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
((double)(200.00000000000000000000000000M/PreciseOne)).ToString("R").Dump(); // 200
```

Comment: I think the key to understanding what's going on is to print out 2E23/1E21 and 2E25/2E23.  The conversion of `Decimal` to `double` is being performed by dividing an integer value by a power of ten even though that can introduce a rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem, and has been the subject of many similar questions on StackOverflow.

The *simplistic* explanation is that decimal numbers can't be exactly represented in binary

[This link](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is an article which might explain the problem.

Comment: That doesn't explain it, actually. *Many* decimal numbers can't be exactly in binary - but in this case the input *can* be exactly represented in binary. Data is being lost unnecessarily.

Comment: Jon, data isn't being lost, on the contrary — it's the *unnecessarily preserved* (from Irchi's POV, no offense) data that's the trouble.

Comment: Anton, see the spec posted by Jon.
The unnecessarily-preserved data should not ruin the conversion. After the 16 significant digits, the decimal value specifies the digits to be all "0". Why should it be rounded to "1" in the 16th position?! "0" is closer to the "exact" decimal value than "1".

Comment: I don't know about 'should', not being a standards man — but this is how it behaves and the only question is what to do about this behaviour.

Comment: @Jon, I have *emphasised* the word 'simplistic' in my answer, for the record.

Comment: @pavium: My point is that I don't believe this is really a case of the normal situation which has led to many other questions. Usually, you have a number which *cannot be exactly represented* as a double. In this case, we don't.

Comment: @Jon, yes you're right, I hadn't looked at it that carefully: the numbers are pretty much integers. There's no reason why data should be 'lost', it must be in the `decimal` to `double` conversion