# C# double to decimal precision loss

Tags: c#, double, decimal, precision

I have a double `"138630.78380386264"` and I want to convert it to a decimal, however when I do so I do it either by casting or by using `Convert.ToDecimal()` and I lose precision.

What's going on? Both decimal and double can hold this number:

[image]

```
double doub = double.Parse("138630.78380386264");
decimal dec = decimal.Parse("138630.78380386264");
string decs = dec.ToString("F17");
string doubse =DoubleConverter.ToExactString(doub);
string doubs = doub.ToString("F17");

decimal decC = (decimal) doub;
string doudeccs = decC.ToString("F17");
decimal decConv = Convert.ToDecimal(doub);
string doudecs = decConv.ToString("F17");
```

Also: how can I get the `ToString()` on double to print out the same result as the debugger shows? e.g. `138630.78380386264`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion of a decimal to double number in C# results in a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584314/conversion-of-a-decimal-to-double-number-in-c-results-in-a-difference)

Comment: Well Convert.ToDecimal(somedouble) is exactly equal to (decimal)somedouble, so no surprises there. I'm not sure why that cast rounds the last digit down though.

Comment: @harold You were tricked. It does round to nearest. The double value finishes 386264 and the 15 sig fig decimal ends 3863.

Comment: @David sneaky stuff - so it's really the debug view that is wrong

Comment: @harold I think you were tricked by the yellow highlighting which is in the wrong place. Just could up to 15 and you'll see what I mean. I was tricked too!

Comment: haha! sorry about the yellow formatting! Thank you to all of the commenters on this question, i understand what is going on now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`138630.78380386264` is not exactly representable to double precision. The closest double precision number (as found [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=138630.78380386264)) is `138630.783803862635977566242218017578125`, which agrees with your findings.

You ask why the conversion to decimal does not contain more precision. The [documentation for `Convert.ToDecimal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0.aspx) has the answer:

> The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest. The following example illustrates how the Convert.ToDecimal(Double) method uses rounding to nearest to return a Decimal value with 15 significant digits.

The double value, rounded to nearest at 15 significant figures is `138630.783803863`, exactly as you show above.

Comment: so why doesnt the conversion to decimal pick up more of the precision?

Comment: ok thanks for explaining that. Is there anyway to get the ToString to print out more than 15 sig fig?  - I'd like to be able to get back to the original string - that way i could get Double to parse the string and do the conversion without loosing precision

Comment: `doub.ToString("G17")` will give you the same string that the debugger produces. But I don't know for sure that's what the debugger is doing. Since `double` has limited precision you won't in general be able to parse the string and then get the original string back. If you need to know the original string, remember it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try "G17" - problem is the double is being produced via com interop so i cant get a string for it :(

Comment: @GreyCloud because Double only *has* a bit more than 15 decimal digits of precision. Everything after that is artifacts of the binary fraction format. The method assumes that you're only interested in the "real" precision, not the accidental one.

Comment: @Michael - so the debugger should only show 15 decimal digits? i wonder why it doesn't...

Answer (score 6):

It is a unfortunate, I think. Near 139,000, a `Decimal` has far better precision than a `Double`. But still, because of this issue, we have **different** `Double`s being projected onto **the same** `Decimal`. For example

```
double doub1 = 138630.7838038626;
double doub2 = 138630.7838038628;
Console.WriteLine(doub1 < doub2);                    // true, values differ as doubles
Console.WriteLine((decimal)doub1 < (decimal)doub2);  // false, values projected onto same decimal
```

In fact there are **six** different representable `Double` values **between** `doub1` and `doub2` above, so they are not the same.

Here is a somewhat silly work-aronud:

```
static decimal PreciseConvert(double doub)
{
  // Handle infinities and NaN-s first (throw exception)
  // Otherwise:
  return Decimal.Parse(doub.ToString("R"), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
}
```

The `"R"` format string ensures that enough extra figures are included to make the mapping injective (in the domain where `Decimal` has superior precision).

---

Note that in some range, a `long` (`Int64`) has a precision that is superior to that of `Double`. So I checked if conversions here are made in the same way (first rounding to 15 significant decimal places). They are not! So:

```
double doub3 = 1.386307838038626e18;
double doub4 = 1.386307838038628e18;

Console.WriteLine(doub3 < doub4);              // true, values differ as doubles
Console.WriteLine((long)doub3 < (long)doub4);  // true, full precision of double used when converting to long
```

It seems inconsistent to use a different "rule" when the target is `decimal`.

Note that, near this value `1.4e18`, because of this, `(decimal)(long)doub3` produces a more accurate result than just `(decimal)doub3`.

Comment: The problem is not with numbers near 139,000 is because the precision of the double is of 16 digitis, it does not matter if the digits are on the left or right side of the separator, if you decrease this number to 13.86307838038626 you will have the same problem. Decimal has a precision of 32 digits, that's why you don't have this problem.

Comment: @GabrielVonlantenC.Lopes You are right this problem is not specific to numbers near 139,000. I only considered that number as an example, chosen because that was the number in the original question. In fact all numbers between (very roughly) `1e-12` and `1e+29` have exactly the same issue. Outside this range a `decimal` is either not defined, or does no longer have a higher precision than a `double`. (However, `decimal` has a precision of 28-29 digits.)

Comment: `(decimal)(long)doub3` is only more precise if the exponent is large enough. There is a large loss of precision if the number would have, say `e01` instead of `e18`.

Comment: @Abel, Absolutely, that is the point (edited answer)! Generally, you would expect that going through an intermediate type (here `long`) in the conversion should be _worse_ than converting directly.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here provided you insight in the *why* of the question, but (even though this is many years after you asked it), here's a method to convert a `double` to a `decimal` without rounding to 15 digits. It requires a bit of bit twiddling, though.

Other than casting, which throws an `OverflowException` if the value doesn't fit, or is `NaN`, `INF` or `-INF`, this method gives `false` in the `success` parameter if conversion is not possible. Since `decimal` does not support negative zero, but `double` does, I've ignored that and just return zero.

The following code is not entirely mine, but I couldn't find the original post to give credits to, sorry. Possibly it was taken from [Jon Skeet's code of `ToExactString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24955729/111575), and adopted for binary exact conversion.

```
const decimal DecimalEpsilon = 0.0000000000000000000000000001M;
public static decimal TryToDecimalWithInsignificand(double dbl, out bool succeeded)
{
    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(dbl))
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return decimal.MaxValue;
    }

    if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(dbl))
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return decimal.MinValue;
    }

    if (double.IsNaN(dbl))
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return 0M;
    }

    if (dbl > (double)decimal.MaxValue)
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return decimal.MaxValue;
    }

    if (dbl < (double)decimal.MinValue)
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return decimal.MinValue;
    }

    if (dbl > 0.0 && dbl <= (double)DecimalEpsilon)
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return 0M;
    }

    if (dbl < 0.0 && dbl >= (double)-DecimalEpsilon)
    {
        succeeded = false;
        return 0M;
    }

    // start conversion
    long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(dbl);
    long mantissa = bits & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;        // 52 bits
    long exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FFL) - 1023L;    // next 11 bits
    bool negative = bits < 0;
    decimal fraction = mantissa / (decimal)0x10000000000000L;
    decimal result;

    if (exponent < 0)
    {
        long div = 1 << (int)-exponent;
        result = (fraction + 1) / div;
    }
    else
    {
        long mul = 1L << (int)exponent;
        result = (fraction + 1) * mul;
    }
    succeeded = true;
    if (negative)
    {
        return -1 * result;
    }
    return result;
}
```