# Weird behaviour of Double.ToString()

Tags: c#, double

I am trying to convert the double value `9007199254740992.0` to a string.

But there seems to be a rounding error (the last 2 becomes a 0):

```
(9007199254740992.0).ToString("#")    // Returns "9007199254740990"
(9007199254740992.0).ToString()       // Returns"9.00719925474099E+15"
```

First I thought that maybe the number couldn't be represented as a double. But it can. This can be seen by casting it to a long and then converting it to a string.

```
((long)9007199254740991.0).ToString() // Returns "9007199254740991"
((long)9007199254740992.0).ToString() // Returns "9007199254740992"
```

Also, I found that if I use the ["R" format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RFormatString), it works.

```
(9007199254740992.0).ToString("R")    // Returns "9007199254740992"
```

Can anyone explain why `ToString("#")` doesn't return the double with the integer part at full precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be seen on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision
>   although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. If the value
>   of this instance has greater than 15 digits, ToString returns
>   PositiveInfinitySymbol or NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the
>   expected number. If you require more precision, specify format with
>   the "G17" format specification, which always returns 17 digits of
>   precision, or "R", which returns 15 digits if the number can be
>   represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be
>   represented with maximum precision.

Comment: Interesting. So, if you want to convert a double to a string, and you don't know how many digits of precision it has, you should always use "R" or "G17" (if precision matters to you). This can certainly be a pitfall - I spent quite some time figuring out why my code failed. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: @AndersKellerCarstensen Indeed. See also another issue in [C# double to decimal precision loss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453900/). It is by design. They collapse all the distinct `double` values whose string representations with the `"G15"` format are equal. That loses precision.