# Which C# double literal is not exactly representable as double?

Tags: c#, double, literals

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> For example, the decimal number 0.1 is not representable in binary
>   floating-point of any finite precision

However, in C#

```
string s = 0.1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

writes `0.1`.

I would have expected something like `0.099999999999999999` or so.

I am looking for at least one example double literal that is not exactly representable as a double.

**Edit:**

As others have pointed out, `0.1` is indeed the literal I have been looking for, as the following classic code example shows:

```
double sum = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sum += 0.1;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum.Equals(1.0)); // false
```

There are just weird things going on when doubles are converted to other datatypes. That is not only the case for `string`, as this expression is true: `0.1m.Equals((decimal)0.1)`

Comment: `0.1` Just because the system fudges things when converting it into a string representation doesn't mean that the underlying representation *has* stored `0.1` precisely.

Comment: anything that is not sum of { 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, ... }

Comment: If you can also use Java, there is a very useful class, `java.util.BigDecimal`. It has exact conversion from double, and exact conversion to string. It can do exactly those operations whose result is a finite length decimal. I often use it to analyze floating point issues. For example, `new BigDecimal(0.1).toString()` is "0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625"

Answer (score 10):

I have a [small source file](http://pobox.com/%7Eskeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which print the *exact* value stored in a `double`. Code at the end of the answer, just in case the link goes away. Basically, it fetches the exact bits of the `double`, and goes from there. It's not pretty or efficent, but it works :)

```
string s = DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.1);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

When you just use `0.1.ToString()` the BCL truncates the textual representation for you.

As for which `double` values are exactly representable - basically, you'd need to work out what the closest binary representation is, and see whether that *is* the exact value. Basically it needs to be composed of powers of two (including negative powers of two) within the right range and precision.

For example, 4.75 can be represented exactly, as it's 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup>

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

/// <summary>
/// A class to allow the conversion of doubles to string representations of
/// their exact decimal values. The implementation aims for readability over
/// efficiency.
/// </summary>
public class DoubleConverter
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given double to a string representation of its
    /// exact decimal value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">The double to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>A string representation of the double's exact decimal value.</returns>
    public static string ToExactString (double d)
    {
        if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(d))
            return "+Infinity";
        if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(d))
            return "-Infinity";
        if (double.IsNaN(d))
            return "NaN";

        // Translate the double into sign, exponent and mantissa.
        long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
        // Note that the shift is sign-extended, hence the test against -1 not 1
        bool negative = (bits < 0);
        int exponent = (int) ((bits >> 52) & 0x7ffL);
        long mantissa = bits & 0xfffffffffffffL;

        // Subnormal numbers; exponent is effectively one higher,
        // but there's no extra normalisation bit in the mantissa
        if (exponent==0)
        {
            exponent++;
        }
        // Normal numbers; leave exponent as it is but add extra
        // bit to the front of the mantissa
        else
        {
            mantissa = mantissa | (1L<<52);
        }
        
        // Bias the exponent. It's actually biased by 1023, but we're
        // treating the mantissa as m.0 rather than 0.m, so we need
        // to subtract another 52 from it.
        exponent -= 1075;
        
        if (mantissa == 0) 
        {
            return "0";
        }
        
        /* Normalize */
        while((mantissa & 1) == 0) 
        {    /*  i.e., Mantissa is even */
            mantissa >>= 1;
            exponent++;
        }
        
        /// Construct a new decimal expansion with the mantissa
        ArbitraryDecimal ad = new ArbitraryDecimal (mantissa);
        
        // If the exponent is less than 0, we need to repeatedly
        // divide by 2 - which is the equivalent of multiplying
        // by 5 and dividing by 10.
        if (exponent < 0) 
        {
            for (int i=0; i < -exponent; i++)
                ad.MultiplyBy(5);
            ad.Shift(-exponent);
        } 
        // Otherwise, we need to repeatedly multiply by 2
        else
        {
            for (int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
                ad.MultiplyBy(2);
        }
        
        // Finally, return the string with an appropriate sign
        if (negative)
            return "-"+ad.ToString();
        else
            return ad.ToString();
    }
    
    /// <summary>Private class used for manipulating</summary>
    class ArbitraryDecimal
    {
        /// <summary>Digits in the decimal expansion, one byte per digit</summary>
        byte[] digits;
        /// <summary> 
        /// How many digits are *after* the decimal point
        /// </summary>
        int decimalPoint=0;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Constructs an arbitrary decimal expansion from the given long.
        /// The long must not be negative.
        /// </summary>
        internal ArbitraryDecimal (long x)
        {
            string tmp = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            digits = new byte[tmp.Length];
            for (int i=0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
                digits[i] = (byte) (tmp[i]-'0');
            Normalize();
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies the current expansion by the given amount, which should
        /// only be 2 or 5.
        /// </summary>
        internal void MultiplyBy(int amount)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[digits.Length+1];
            for (int i=digits.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int resultDigit = digits[i]*amount+result[i+1];
                result[i]=(byte)(resultDigit/10);
                result[i+1]=(byte)(resultDigit%10);
            }
            if (result[0] != 0)
            {
                digits=result;
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Copy (result, 1, digits, 0, digits.Length);
            }
            Normalize();
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Shifts the decimal point; a negative value makes
        /// the decimal expansion bigger (as fewer digits come after the
        /// decimal place) and a positive value makes the decimal
        /// expansion smaller.
        /// </summary>
        internal void Shift (int amount)
        {
            decimalPoint += amount;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes leading/trailing zeroes from the expansion.
        /// </summary>
        internal void Normalize()
        {
            int first;
            for (first=0; first < digits.Length; first++)
                if (digits[first]!=0)
                    break;
            int last;
            for (last=digits.Length-1; last >= 0; last--)
                if (digits[last]!=0)
                    break;
            
            if (first==0 && last==digits.Length-1)
                return;
            
            byte[] tmp = new byte[last-first+1];
            for (int i=0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
                tmp[i]=digits[i+first];
            
            decimalPoint -= digits.Length-(last+1);
            digits=tmp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the value to a proper decimal string representation.
        /// </summary>
        public override String ToString()
        {
            char[] digitString = new char[digits.Length];            
            for (int i=0; i < digits.Length; i++)
                digitString[i] = (char)(digits[i]+'0');
            
            // Simplest case - nothing after the decimal point,
            // and last real digit is non-zero, eg value=35
            if (decimalPoint==0)
            {
                return new string (digitString);
            }
            
            // Fairly simple case - nothing after the decimal
            // point, but some 0s to add, eg value=350
            if (decimalPoint < 0)
            {
                return new string (digitString)+
                       new string ('0', -decimalPoint);
            }
            
            // Nothing before the decimal point, eg 0.035
            if (decimalPoint >= digitString.Length)
            {
                return "0."+
                    new string ('0',(decimalPoint-digitString.Length))+
                    new string (digitString);
            }

            // Most complicated case - part of the string comes
            // before the decimal point, part comes after it,
            // eg 3.5
            return new string (digitString, 0, 
                               digitString.Length-decimalPoint)+
                "."+
                new string (digitString,
                            digitString.Length-decimalPoint, 
                            decimalPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Then, why does 0.1.ToString("N99") lie to me even if I specify high precision?

Comment: @Marco: The documentation isn't clear on that, but I believe it's because there's an implicit "maximum digits to return" as a cap for the value you provide, and it's truncating the trailing 0s.

Comment: Even worse, I found that 0.1m.Equals((decimal)0.1). I think that is weird. Do you think this has the same root course as you just explained for the string conversion?

Comment: @Marco: I agree that it's weird. I suspect that that conversion takes the string representation and then parses it again, or some equivalent. It's generally a bad thing to do anyway :)

Comment: @Marco: I would argue that it's not lying to you.  There aren't enough binary digits to justify displaying that many decimal digits.  Displaying more than `53*log(2)/log(10)` (`53*log_10(2)`) digits is misleading.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein, currently MSDN clearly explains this behaviour. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

The BCL cheats here by giving you a rounded value when you print it. There should be no literal that prints a different representation or accuracy.

Which is nice, in that it matches intuition most of the time. But so far I haven't found a nice way of getting the *exact* value to print.

Comment: You can use this: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs Use as `Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d))`

Answer (score 1):

`0.1` is the example. But in C# it is a literal of type `double`. And `Double.ToString()` uses format with precision of 15 instead of 17 digits by default.

Relevant quote from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. [...] If you require more precision, specify format with the "G17" format specification, which always returns 17 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 15 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision.

So, `0.1.ToString("G17")` equals to `"0.10000000000000001"` which is the number `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` from Jon Skeet answer correctly rounded towards infinity. Note that last `1` in first number is 17th significant digit, and first `5` in second number is 18th significant digit. `0.1.ToString()` is basically same as `0.1.ToString("G")` which equals to `"0.1"`. Or `"0.100000000000000"` if you print 15 digits after decimal point. Which is `"0.10000000000000001"` correctly rounded towards zero.

Interestingly, `Convert.ToDecimal(double)` uses only 15 significant digits too.

Relevant quote from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0.aspx):

> The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.

You can use same G17 format and `decimal.Parse()` to convert `0.1` to decimal: `decimal.Parse(0.1.ToString("G17"))`. This code snippet produces number that is not equal to `0.1m`.

For more information check [The General ("G") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString) page on MSDN.