# Unexpected truncation when converting a decimal to a double

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion, decimal

When converting a decimal to a double, sometimes there is some unexpected truncation.
For example:

```
        decimal dec = -96.31614743511301m;
        double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(dec);  // dbl = -96.316147435113, why?
```

For other values it works as expected:

```
        decimal dec2 = -96.269592225955307m;
        double dbl2 = Convert.ToDouble(dec2); // dbl2 = -96.269592225955307, expected
```

Note that the second example which works actually has more decimal places than the first which doesn't.  Also, the first value can be converted successfully into a double using this convoluted code:

```
        dbl = Convert.ToDouble(dec.ToString()); // dbl = -96.31614743511301, expected
```

So why is the double value truncated in the first example?

Answer (score 3):

Decimal and double are stored differently with different accuracy... see here - [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: Storage details aside, it seems that if both double and decimal are capable of storing the value -96.31614743511301, then conversion from one to the other should work without truncating the value.

Why does this work without truncation...

    double dbl = Convert.ToDouble("-96.31614743511301");

but this results in truncation...

    decimal dec = -96.31614743511301m;
    double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(dec);

Comment: This looks like a bug...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584314/conversion-of-a-decimal-to-double-number-in-c-sharp-results-in-a-difference?rq=1