# Inaccuracy of decimal in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, floating-accuracy

Yesterday during debugging something strange happened to me and I can't really explain it:

[image: Decimal calculation]

[image: Decimal calculations with brackets]

So maybe I am not seeing the obvious here or I misunderstood something about decimals in .NET but shouldn't the results be the same?

Comment: you may follow the [Floating point issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584314/conversion-of-a-decimal-to-double-number-in-c-sharp-results-in-a-difference)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/1394393. Not a dupe. (At the least, this hones in on an aspect that's commonly misunderstood.)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`decimal` is not a magical *do all the maths for me* type. It's still a floating point number - the main difference from `float` is that it's a *decimal* floating point number, rather than *binary*. So you can easily represent `0.3` as a decimal (it's impossible as a finite binary number), but you don't have infinite precision.

This makes it work much closer to a human doing the same calculations, but you still have to imagine someone doing each operation individually. It's specifically designed for financial calculations, where you don't do the kind of thing you do in Maths - you simply go step by step, rounding each result according to pretty specific rules.

In fact, for many cases, `decimal` might work much worse than `float` (or better, `double`). This is because `decimal` doesn't do any automatic rounding at all. Doing the same with `double` gives you 22 as expected, because it's automatically assumed that the difference doesn't matter - in `decimal`, it *does* - that's one of the important points about `decimal`. You can emulate this by inserting manual `Math.Round`s, of course, but it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 31):

`Decimal` can only store exactly values that are exactly representable in decimal *within its precision limit*. Here 22/24 = 0.91666666666666666666666... which needs **infinite precision** or a **rational type** to store, and it does not equal to 22/24 after rounding anymore.

If you do the multiplication first then all the intermediate results are exactly representable, hence the result you see.

Answer (score 13):

By adding brackets you are making sure that the division is calculated before the multiplication. This subtlely looks to be enough to affect the calculation enough to introduce a [floating precision issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision_and_backward_error_analysis).

Since computers can't actually produce every possible number, you should make sure you factor this into your calculations

Comment: As a small note, humans can't actually produce every possible number either. `1 / 3` is a great example of this since everyone will decide what precision is enough for them and never try to figure out if there is ever a resolution. (Spoiler: there isn't. its always recursive 3's)

Comment: The cool thing humans can do, though, is keep it as `1 / 3` for the rest of the calculation, or write `0.33`(infinite expansion). Even for irrational numbers, we can write out how they are defined, or just use a constant. Pretty handy when you're really serious about precision :D

Comment: This answer explains the cause very well. If you need to manipulate with high precision numbers, you'd better use BigDecimal data type.

Comment: @Luaan Or switch to ternary at that point in the calculation and write 0.1. :)

Comment: @Luaan: Computers can do that cool thing too. It's just that they obey when you tell them to do their calculations with finite precision floating point numbers.

Comment: Both humans and computers are fine at knowing that `1/3` is `0.1` in floating-point base-3.

Comment: `1 / 3` is precisely `0.4` in base 12.

Answer (score 1):

While `Decimal` has a higher precision than `Double`, its primary useful feature is that every value *precisely matches its human-readable representation*.  While the fixed-decimal types which are available in some languages can guarantee that neither addition or subtraction of two matching-precision fixed-point values, nor multiplication of a fixed-point type by an integer, will ever cause rounding error, and while "big-decimal" types such as those found in Java can guarantee that no multiplication will ever cause rounding errors, floating-point `Decimal` types like the one found in .NET offers no such guarantees, and no decimal types can guarantee that division operations can be completed without rounding errors (Java's has the option to throw an exception in case rounding would be necessary).

While those deciding to make `Decimal` be a floating-point type may have intended that it be usable either for situations requiring more digits to the right of the decimal point or more to the left, floating-point types, whether base-10 or base-2, make rounding issues unavoidable for all operations.